# Which settings should I use for transparent video?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, animation-rendering, rendering

I've created some graphics in Adobe After Effects which have a transparent background. I wish to render these and maintain the transparent background in the final video file so I can easily import them in my editing software. I've looked on the internet and most video tutorials show that QuickTime Animation is used to render transparent video but over the last few years support has been removed from adobe products for that video format (since premiere version 12.1).

What video codec/format should I use for my graphics? If QuickTime is still preferable, how should I import it into Premiere Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally use ProRes 4444 set to "RGB + Alpha" and "Millions of Colours+"

[image: screenshot]